# How do I create an AngularJS directive based on another directive logic?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am pretty new to AngularJS and creating directives.

Lets say I wanted a "delayed ng-show", that means it should work like `ng-show`, but the element should be visible after 2 seconds as opposed to immediately the expression was fulfilled. I don't want to change the current behavior of `ng-show`, just to create a new `ng-delayed-show` directive.

Can anyone give me an example or link me to direct documentation on how to *reuse* or create a *sub directive* of another directive?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create directive for this. You can very well do it using animation capabilities of AngularJS which internally uses CSS capability called easing.

Read documentation for ngshow and it's animation section here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow

Since i am not very familiar with it, this post can help you http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html#how-to-use-animations-in-angularjs

Comment: I have read about ng-show, but I would rather want to know how to create a new directive based on another :-)