# Directives: translating one attribute expression to another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In several places, I'm creating a table which has two or more variants. It shows the main data and some details columns. The main data are always the same and the details vary according to user's selection. Let's say, it looks like either

```
Name Count LongDescription Price
```

or

```
Name Count Availability    Price
```

or

```
Name Count Weigth Volume   Price
```

It boils down to tons of

- `ng-if="detail=='description'"`
- `ng-if="detail=='availability'"`
- `ng-if="detail=='description' || "detail=='availability'"`

First I shortened the nice descriptive names to a single letter in order to remove the clutter. Then I thought to employ some convention and create my own directive called `detail`:

```
detail="d"     => ng-if="detail=='d'"
detail="da"    => ng-if="detail=='d' || detail=='a'"
```

or maybe

```
detail="da"    => ng-if="'da'.contains(detail)"
```

I got it (sort of) working by copying and adapting the source of `ngIfDirective`, but creating a directive translating to `ng-if` feels cleaner. So my questions:

- What way is better?
- How can I write the directive translating to a different one?

Comment: Don't get it. What is the expected outcome?

Comment: @Dalorzo: Just a replacement of the many complicated `ng-if`s conditions by much simpler conditions. The title of my question could be [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097510).

Comment: "... **I'm creating** a table ..." - So why do you need `ng-if` then?

Comment: @zeroflagL: Because the table has some columns to be displayed conditionally. I could restructure it somehow, but whatever I do, I end up repeating either conditions (as now) or repeating the common parts. Or maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted the question. I got the impression that you create a table that can have different columns, but once the table is created the columns don't change.

Comment: @zeroflagL: They do. There are radio buttons allowing to switch between the different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your attribute restricted directive add a new ng-if attribute whose value is generated based on its own value, then recompile:

```
.directive('detail', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if(!attrs.ngIf) { // prevent infinite loop
        switch (attrs.detail) {
          case 'd':
            attrs.$set('ngIf', "detail == 'd'");
            break;
          case 'a':
            attrs.$set('ngIf', "detail == 'a'");
            break;  
          case 'da':
            attrs.$set('ngIf', "detail == 'd' || detail =='a'");
            break;
        }
        $compile(elem)(scope); // relink directive element
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<div detail="d">My element exists because: <b>$scope.detail == 'd'</b></div>
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/W8PQhn12b0qiSNTXgP9w?p=preview)

Comment: From what I've learned now I'd say that this should be done in the compile phase. I tried and failed. However, your solution works fine.